# How to deploy to Nexus Sonatype new Maven module

Tags: maven, nexus

I'm creating new module for existing Maven project. When I try to `mvn:install` project from Idea it throughs these error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for kz.alfabank:type-ortalyk-bazar:bundle:1.0
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ kz.alfabank:type-ortalyk-bazar:${kz.alfabank.type.ortalyk-bazar.version}, C:\Users\u8002\Documents\dev\alfa-bank\kz.alfabank.soa\kz.alfabank.soa\type-ortalyk-bazar\pom.xml, line 19, column 14
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building type-ortalyk-bazar 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://vserver266:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to public (http://vserver266:8081/nexus/content/groups/public): Failed to transfer file: http://vserver266:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 504 , ReasonPhrase:Connection Timed Out.
Downloading: http://vserver266:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to public (http://vserver266:8081/nexus/content/groups/public): Failed to transfer file: http://vserver266:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 504 , ReasonPhrase:Connection Timed Out.
Downloading: http://vserver266:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to public (http://vserver266:8081/nexus/content/groups/public): Failed to transfer file: http://vserver266:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 504 , ReasonPhrase:Connection Timed Out.
Downloading: http://vserver266:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/kz/alfabank/type-ortalyk-bazar/1.0/type-ortalyk-bazar-1.0.jar
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/kz/alfabank/type-ortalyk-bazar/1.0/type-ortalyk-bazar-1.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 03:03 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-11T14:01:00+06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/167M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project type-ortalyk-bazar: Could not resolve dependencies for project kz.alfabank:type-ortalyk-bazar:bundle:1.0: Could not find artifact kz.alfabank:type-ortalyk-bazar:jar:1.0 in public (http://vserver266:8081/nexus/content/groups/public) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

We use as a repository Sonatype Nexus 2.11.4. Why Maven looks for newly created module in Nexus repository? And seems that some metadata files cannot be downloaded from Nexus :/

Comment: First it looks like you have network issues: `Return code is: 504 , ReasonPhrase:Connection Timed Out.`...

Comment: Check your settings.xml file to see if an http proxy has been configured, if there is one, add the  nexus host name to the nonProxyHosts:  https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Answer (score 3):

If dependencies are not available in local repository or other dependencies are not built or downloaded prior to the current module build that is when it looks within the remote repositories. 
Please do look for the artifact **kz.alfabank:type-ortalyk-bazar:jar:1.0** is present in the in your .m2 repo

Note: If you are using IntelliJ within the setting try offline mode